# routing to users device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, device

iam trying to remember how to code since 3 months of stoping, so in my new project trying to add a link_to that goes to the device users sign_in page..kept getting this error.

```
NameError in Topics#index
undefined local variable or method `new_user_session' for #<#<Class:0x74e5db0>:0x54af248>
```

route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :topics
  devise_for :admins, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :users

  root 'topics#index'
```

here is my routes

```
Prefix Verb       URI Pattern                          Controller#Action
                       topics GET        /topics(.:format)                    topics#index
                              POST       /topics(.:format)                    topics#create
                    new_topic GET        /topics/new(.:format)                topics#new
                   edit_topic GET        /topics/:id/edit(.:format)           topics#edit
                        topic GET        /topics/:id(.:format)                topics#show
                              PATCH      /topics/:id(.:format)                topics#update
                              PUT        /topics/:id(.:format)                topics#update
                              DELETE     /topics/:id(.:format)                topics#destroy
            new_admin_session GET        /admin/login(.:format)               active_admin/devise/sessions#new
                admin_session POST       /admin/login(.:format)               active_admin/devise/sessions#create
        destroy_admin_session DELETE|GET /admin/logout(.:format)              active_admin/devise/sessions#destroy
               admin_password POST       /admin/password(.:format)            active_admin/devise/passwords#create
           new_admin_password GET        /admin/password/new(.:format)        active_admin/devise/passwords#new
          edit_admin_password GET        /admin/password/edit(.:format)       active_admin/devise/passwords#edit
                              PATCH      /admin/password(.:format)            active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                              PUT        /admin/password(.:format)            active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                   admin_root GET        /admin(.:format)                     admin/dashboard#index
    batch_action_admin_admins POST       /admin/admins/batch_action(.:format) admin/admins#batch_action
                 admin_admins GET        /admin/admins(.:format)              admin/admins#index
                              POST       /admin/admins(.:format)              admin/admins#create
              new_admin_admin GET        /admin/admins/new(.:format)          admin/admins#new
             edit_admin_admin GET        /admin/admins/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/admins#edit
                  admin_admin GET        /admin/admins/:id(.:format)          admin/admins#show
                              PATCH      /admin/admins/:id(.:format)          admin/admins#update
                              PUT        /admin/admins/:id(.:format)          admin/admins#update
                              DELETE     /admin/admins/:id(.:format)          admin/admins#destroy
              admin_dashboard GET        /admin/dashboard(.:format)           admin/dashboard#index
     batch_action_admin_users POST       /admin/users/batch_action(.:format)  admin/users#batch_action
                  admin_users GET        /admin/users(.:format)               admin/users#index
                              POST       /admin/users(.:format)               admin/users#create
               new_admin_user GET        /admin/users/new(.:format)           admin/users#new
              edit_admin_user GET        /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format)      admin/users#edit
                   admin_user GET        /admin/users/:id(.:format)           admin/users#show
                              PATCH      /admin/users/:id(.:format)           admin/users#update
                              PUT        /admin/users/:id(.:format)           admin/users#update
                              DELETE     /admin/users/:id(.:format)           admin/users#destroy
               admin_comments GET        /admin/comments(.:format)            admin/comments#index
                              POST       /admin/comments(.:format)            admin/comments#create
                admin_comment GET        /admin/comments/:id(.:format)        admin/comments#show
                              DELETE     /admin/comments/:id(.:format)        admin/comments#destroy
             new_user_session GET        /users/sign_in(.:format)             devise/sessions#new
                 user_session POST       /users/sign_in(.:format)             devise/sessions#create
         destroy_user_session DELETE     /users/sign_out(.:format)            devise/sessions#destroy
                user_password POST       /users/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#create
            new_user_password GET        /users/password/new(.:format)        devise/passwords#new
           edit_user_password GET        /users/password/edit(.:format)       devise/passwords#edit
                              PATCH      /users/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#update
                              PUT        /users/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#update
     cancel_user_registration GET        /users/cancel(.:format)              devise/registrations#cancel
            user_registration POST       /users(.:format)                     devise/registrations#create
        new_user_registration GET        /users/sign_up(.:format)             devise/registrations#new
       edit_user_registration GET        /users/edit(.:format)                devise/registrations#edit
                              PATCH      /users(.:format)                     devise/registrations#update
                              PUT        /users(.:format)                     devise/registrations#update
                              DELETE     /users(.:format)                     devise/registrations#destroy
                         root GET        /                                    topics#index
```

index.erb

```
<div id="pre_header" class="visible-lg" style="background-color:#E4AB7E; height:5px;"></div>
    <div id="header" class="container" style="background-color:#fff; background-image:none;">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <div class="logo">
              <%= link_to (image_tag 'logo.jpg',:style=>'padding:20px 50px;'), root_path %>
            </div>
            <!-- End Logo -->
            <!-- Top Menu -->
            <div class="col-md-12 margin-top-30">
                <div id="hornav" class="pull-right visible-lg">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><%= link_to 'Laman Utama', topics_path %></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Senarai Ilmu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Hubungi Kami</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Info Lanjut</a></li>
                        <li><%= link_to 'Log Masuk',new_user_session %></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <!-- End Top Menu -->
              </div>
</div>

<div id="pre_header" class="visible-lg" style="background-color:#E4AB7E; height:5px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo I guess. `path` is missing in the link. It would be `new_user_session_path`

```
<li><%= link_to 'Log Masuk',new_user_session_path %></li>
```

Comment: owh really forgot hat i should add path there.. ty!